# Spring Convert Annotation Configuration to XML

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have the following code snippet which I use to expose a `BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` Bean through Annotation Configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    public class SpringConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public static BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getProperties() {

            File conf = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath() + "/configuration.properties");

            BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer;
            configurer = new BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();

            Resource[] resources = {
                    new FileSystemResource(conf.getAbsolutePath())
            };

            configurer.setLocations(resources);

            return configurer;
        }
    }
```

So basically, I want to expose a properties file that is located in the same folder as the jar. Thats why I'm doing the crazy stuff with `File`

Is there anyway however which I could convert this into XML configuration?
Something like:

```
    <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="#{new File('.')....}"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: maybe the `@Value` annotation

Comment: Be careful that `new File(".")` will get you a file in a current working directory, which might not be the same as the location of your JAR. Also note that Spring is more than capable to convert string into `FileSystemResource` if you use `file:` prefix/protocol (`file:configuration.properties` might work in a same way as your code).

Answer (score 0):

You can create the bean using a factory:

```
<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerFactory"
    class="foo.bar.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerFactory" />

<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder"
    factory-bean="bridgePropertyPlaceholderFactory"
    factory-method="createBridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />
```

Java factory:

```
public class BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerFactory {
  public BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer createBridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    // your creation code ..
    return ..
  }
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) for more details on factory methods.